# Can we remove the given space b/w printed stars and they get close to each other

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("*")
print("*")
print("*")
print("*")
```

How to remove this space is it possible...
*
*
*
*

Comment: `print("*","*","*","*",sep="")` . If you don't wants to use different print statement. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Damini It helped. By mistakes i put star in one line, I wanted to ask can we remove sapce bw the stars as given below.  Thank for ur answer.
*
*
*
*

Answer (score 0):

```
print("*","*","*","*",sep="")
```